# How to transfer large number of SPL tokens?

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, spl, anchor-spl

`pub fn transfer<'info>(ctx: CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Transfer<'info>>, amount: u64) -> Result<()>`

The above code is the method defenition used in rust to transfer SPL tokens. The amount argument is accepted as u64. What if we want to transfer more than U64_MAX ?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum amount of tokens for an SPL token mint is `u64::MAX`. The `supply` is stored as a `u64` at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/177a6c94d751e49be0e299b0155823195a21e7fe/token/program/src/state.rs#L25

Since it's impossible to have more than `u64::MAX` tokens, you'll never need to transfer more than that.

If you want, however, you can fork the SPL token program and modify it to represent amounts as `u128` or a custom 256-bit uint type. It just might be difficult to get adoption in the ecosystem for your program.